# boost error: expression cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use the boost RK4 integration together with the rigid body dynamics library.
I am getting a strange error I dont recognize, that I think has to do with the `operator()` override but I am not sure based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963340/boost-odeint-too-many-arguments-to-function)  post.

My code is similar to [this](https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/master/examples/harmonic_oscillator.cpp) example. Which makes me think that either I am missing something obvious. I think that it may be a compiler problem.

This is my class I use to convert from RBDL to boost.

```cpp
class rbdlToBoost {

    public:
        rbdlToBoost(Model* model) : model(model)
        {
            q = VectorNd::Zero(model->dof_count);
            qd = VectorNd::Zero(model->dof_count);
            qdd = VectorNd::Zero(model->dof_count);
            tau = VectorNd::Zero(model->dof_count);

        }

        //3c. Boost uses this 'operator()' function to evaluate the state
        //    derivative of the pendulum.
        void operator() (const state_type &x,  state_type &dxdt, const double t)
        {

            //do stuff


        }

    
    private:
        Model* model;
        VectorNd q, qd, qdd, tau;

};
```

This is my main I am using to test the integration. This is a minimal example I put together.

```cpp
#include "rbdl/Model.h"
#include "rbdl/Dynamics.h"

#include "rbdl_model_tests/DynamicTesting.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int     nPts    = 100;
  double  t0      = 0;
  double  t1      = 3;


  double t        = 0;             //time
  double ts       = 0;            //scaled time
  double dtsdt    = M_PI/(t1-t0);    //dertivative scaled time 
  double tp = 0;
  double dt   = (t1-t0)/((double)nPts);   

  //Integration settings
  double absTolVal   = 1e-10;
  double relTolVal   = 1e-6;
  double a_x = 1.0 , a_dxdt = 1.0;
  Model* model  = NULL;
  model         = new Model();
  rbdlToBoost rbdlBoostModel(model);
  state_type xState(2);
  int steps = 0;
  xState[0] = -M_PI/4.0;
  xState[1] = 0;
  controlled_stepper_type controlled_stepper(
                                             default_error_checker< double , range_algebra , default_operations >
                                             ( absTolVal , relTolVal , a_x , a_dxdt ) 
                                             );
   integrate_adaptive( 
        controlled_stepper ,
        model , xState , tp , t , (t-tp)/10 );//This seems to be the problem
      tp = t;

  return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```sh
~/catkin_ws/src/ambf_control_system/rbdl_model_tests/src/tempDyn.cpp:37:47:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/controlled_runge_kutta.hpp:481:12: error: expression cannot be used as a function
         sys( x , m_dxdt.m_v ,t );
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a simple fix
I just had to change.

I was passing in the wrong variable into the function. I had to pass in my custom class variable (rbdlBoostModel) not my RBDL model (model).

```cpp
 integrate_adaptive( 
        controlled_stepper ,
        model , xState , tp , t , (t-tp)/10 );//This seems to be the problem
```

to

```cpp
      integrate_adaptive( 
          controlled_stepper ,
          rbdlBoostModel , xState , tp , t , (t-tp)/10 );
```